# Confused about encapsulation in Python

Tags: python, encapsulation

I am reading about encapsulation on google from last 3 hours, in some blogs they define encapsulation as the bundling of data members and methods into a single unit, while in some places
they confuse encapsulation with data hiding. Please clear my confusion what actually is encapsulation, is it a  data hiding or bundling bundling of data members and methods into a single unit or both? Thanks

Comment: Many concepts in computer science don't have firm definitions, and this is one of them. Both definitions are used in different contexts. Some languages don't have data hiding, so the only form of encapsulation they provide is bundling.

Comment: Python is one of the languages without data hiding. Object attributes can be accessed directly, although there's a kludgey way to emulate private members.

Comment: @Barmar what about the languages like C++, where data hiding is the part of the design of C++...

Comment: Exactly. Whether information hiding is available depends on the language. They're both examples of encapsulation.

Comment: @Barmar I am really confused because after some days I have a coding interview, if my interviewer will ask me about encapsulation. what should I answer?? please guide me

Comment: Tell him that it has multiple meanings and describe them. Or pick one and describe it.

Comment: As I was taught in my university: hiding data and especially restricting access to the data via classes and methods is called `encapsulation`, while combining pretty similar data and methods that work with it in a single class/module is usually called `decomposition`.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation means the bundling of data with methods that operate on them, in turn hiding the actual data behind these methods. So both definitions are somewhat correct.
The methods can then be used to control what a value some data can be, e.g. prevent it to be `null`.

Edit: Check the comments on your question, they also have interesting information.

- Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is a combination of both. It refers to the idea of bundling all the pieces needed to operate on certain data objects together. This way you have all the data and the methods in one "place". It both bundles things and hides the underlying data.

I would say that the two most important parts of encapsulation are: 1) modularity and 2) protecting modules/objects from being accessed in a way that is not explicitly allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As I was taught in my university: hiding data and especially restricting access to the data via classes and methods is called **encapsulation**, while combining pretty similar data and methods that work with it in a single class/module is usually called **decomposition**.

**Encapsulation** is needed to decrease the number of bugs and protect data from incorrect changes, while **decomposition** makes your code more readable.

In Python there are many ways to decompose your code: you can gather methods and data in classes, gather classes in modules, modules in packages...

Python (from the box) doesn't give you opportunities to restrict access to the fields of the class or elements of the module (you can always monkey-patch the module). However, it doesn't mean, that you can not do some encapsulation. You can name data variables for inner use with a low dash. You also can use nested classes for hiding data (they also can help with decomposition sometimes). And of course, create properties.

Well encapsulated code (from GeeksForGeeks) looks like:

```
class Person:
     def __init__(self):
          self._age = 0
       
     @property
     def age(self):
         print("getter method called")
         return self._age
       
     @age.setter
     def age(self, a):
         if(a < 18):
            raise ValueError("Sorry you age is below eligibility criteria")
         print("setter method called")
         self._age = a
```

It is only *unconditional agreement* that we will use `Person().age` instead of `Person()._age`. However, I'll believe that it is enough for 99% of people.